# Kendo UI grid with large data set

Tags: grid, kendo-ui

I am trying Kendo UI out and I am using the examples provided for studying purpose. Let's suppose I am using a large data source of several hundreds of thousand elements. If I'm using paging and the page size is 10, I would really like to be able to get only 10 elements from the web-page and if Kendo UI was able to know that in reality the number of elements is much bigger, but we are showing only 10.

This is what I currently have:

```
        var initGrid = true;
        var grid2Data;

        function getDataSource()
        {
            return grid2Data.Data;
        }

        var grid;
        function getPageIndex()
        {
            if (!(grid)) {
                return 0;
            }
            return grid.pager.page() - 1;
        }

        function getPageSize() {
            if (!(grid)) {
                return 10;
            }
            return grid.pager.pageSize();
        }

        function getFilters() {
            if (!(grid)) {
                return "";
            }
            return grid.dataSource.filter();
        }

        function getSorts() {
            if (!(grid)) {
                return "";
            }
            return grid.dataSource.sort();
        }

        function getParams() {
            return getPageSize();
        }

        function postTest() {
            if (initGrid) {
                $.post('myurl' + getParams(), function (data) {
                    grid2Data = data;
                    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataBound: onDataBound,
                        dataSource: {
                            data: getDataSource(),
                            schema: {
                                model: {
                                    fields: {
                                        Email: { type: "string" },
                                        FullName: { type: "string" },
                                        LogCreateDate: { type: "date" },
                                        RoleName: { type: "string" },
                                        UserName: { type: "string" }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            pageSize: 10
                        },
                        height: 300,
                        scrollable: false,
                        sortable: true,
                        filterable: true,
                        pageable: {
                            input: true,
                            numeric: false
                        },
                        columns: [
                        {
                            field: "Email",
                            title: "Email",
                            width: 100
                        },
                        {
                            field: "FullName",
                            title: "Full Name",
                            width: 100
                        },
                        {
                            field: "LogCreateDate",
                            title: "Created",
                            template: '#= kendo.toString(LogCreateDate,"MM/dd/yyyy") #'
                        },
                        {
                            field: "RoleName",
                            title: "Role",
                            width: 50
                        },
                        {
                            field: "UserName",
                            width: 100
                        }
                    ]
                    });
                    grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
                });
            }
            else {
            }
            initGrid = false;
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            postTest();
        });
```

My problem is that the grid is showing that this is element 1-10 from 10 and it's the first page. I would like the grid to show me a page index and item count given by me. How can I set the number of elements and the page index of the grid? Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you choose `serverPaging` in the `DataSource` by setting it to `true`. You receiver in the server information about the page number (`page`), the page size (`pageSize`), number of records to skip (`skip`)... (look for serverPaging in http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource) and in exchange you should return not only the array with the data of that page but also the total number of rows. Then you implement in `schema.total` the function for accessing the number of records. I.e. Lets assume that you return as result the following object:

```
{
    rows: [ 
        { id: 1, col1: "col1.1", col2: "col1.2" },
        { id: 2, col1: "col2.1", col2: "col2.2" },
        { id: 3, col1: "col3.1", col2: "col3.2" }
    ],
    totalRows : 1000
}
```

Then you might implement `schema.total` as:

```
schema: {
    total: function (response) {
        return response.totalRows;
    }
}
```

Where `response` is the object received from the server.

**NOTE:** Actually in this case would be enough defining the `schema` as:

```
schema: {
    total: "totalRows";
    }
}
```

Since `total` is directly stored in `totalRows` field.

Check http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/remote-data.html for an example.